# Is there a way in SQLAlchemy ORM to map a single table of vertically stored lists?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, dimensional-modeling

I have a (read-only, not managed by me) database that is composed of a number of fact tables of various dimensions. The actual data contained within those tables can be either scalar (int/numeric) or vectorial (list of int/numeric). The vectors and scalars are stored in separate tables so that the vectors can be stored vertically (stored as scalars with an extra `VECTOR_INDEX` dimension which indicates that element's position inside the vector).

Vector tables therefore all look somewhat like this:

```
+-------+-------+--------------+--------+--------+
| key_a | key_b | vector_index | data_u | data_v |
+-------+-------+--------------+--------+--------+
|     1 |     1 |            1 | 123    |    456 |
|     1 |     1 |            2 | 234    |    567 |
|     1 |     1 |            3 | <null> |    678 |
|     1 |     1 |            4 | <null> |    789 |
|     1 |     2 |            1 | 111    |    222 |
+-------+-------+--------------+--------+--------+
```

I'm already using SQLAlchemy for other things, and I'm trying to see if I can get the ORM to convert those vertical vectors into dicts or lists for me. The SQLAlchemy documentation has [an example of how to work with vertically stored data](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/vertical/dictlike.html), but the problem here is that `attribute_mapped_collection("key")` only works when applied to a relationship.

If I attempt to do the same and define the vector table as "related" to my scalar table, it "technically works":

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship, joinedload
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection

Base = declarative_base()

class FactTable_Vec(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fact_table_v"

    key_a = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    key_b = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    vector_index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Vector data
    data_u = Column(Integer)
    data_v = Column(Integer)


class FactTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fact_table"

    key_a = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    key_b = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Scalar data
    data_x = Column(Integer)
    data_y = Column(Integer)

    _vector_data = relationship(
        "FactTable_Vec",
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("vector_index"),
        uselist=True,
        primaryjoin="and_(FactTable.key_a == foreign(FactTable_Vec.key_a), FactTable.key_b == foreign(FactTable_Vec.key_b))",
    )

    data_u = association_proxy('_vector_data', 'data_u')
    data_v = association_proxy('_vector_data', 'data_v')

def fetch_info(db_sess):
    query = db_sess.query(FactTable).options(joinedload(FactTable._vector_data)).filter(and_(FactTable.key_a == 1))

    for item in query.all():
        print(item.key_a, item.key_b, item.data_u, item.data_v)
```

This does what I want, **it returns `data_u` and `data_v` as dicts keyed by their vector index**, but the performance penality from joining between those two fact tables (which isn't even needed since the keys I'm filtering on are shared between both tables and I don't need any of the data from the scalar table in this case) is *colossal*, so that's not really an option.

Is it possible to have something akin to an `attribute_mapped_collection` for a single table? To "aggregate" those vertically-stored vectors into dicts (possibly active dicts, but that wouldn't matter in my use-case) in the same ORM-friendly way without having to include a join?

Comment: Before doing anything else, I would try adding ```index=True``` to any column you are joining on. That should increase your performance. You would think specifying ```primary_key``` in SQLAlchemy would automatically index your ids, but I don't think it does.

Comment: Oh, those columns are indexed, don't worry. The table I happen to be operating upon is already defined, the ORM is something I'm evaluating as an alternative interface.

With that said, indexes wouldn't be all that helpful if I somehow need to access a large percentage of all records on the table, since I still need to perform a (very large) join I would rather avoid.

Comment: This is a tough one. If I had to use this db, I would probably be tempted to migrate all the data to a schema that worked better for my queries rather than trying to fix it on the SQLAlchemy level. It's a one-time cost, so I guess it depends on how big the database is. Also, if you need to keep coming back to the database because it's been updated.

Comment: Querying that table isn't the issue, I'm doing ok right now with SQLA core queries, it's just that it's a roadblock in adapting this into an ORM model. My question had more to do with practical ways of representing dimentional fact tables like this (without joins) using the SQLA ORM. Migrating the schema wouldn't be an option, anyway, there are very good reason why that vector part is stored vertically.

Comment: I'm sure there is! Good luck!

Comment: If anyone from the future wants to know, I didn't find anything and gave up on the idea. I just stuck with hand-made SQLA Core queries instead of using the ORM.